# How can I get Travis-CI to recognize and open external files during testing

Tags: python, travis-ci

The last few failing builds pass fine on my computer, but I am having trouble getting them to pass on travis.  The problem is coming from there few lines in the tests (and other similar operations): https://github.com/garth5689/pyd2l/blob/master/test/pyd2l_test.py#L15-L20

In my tests, since I have complicated data to test against, I have pickled this data to easily open it back up again and not have to hit the website I'm scraping multiple times every time I test.  (Feel free to discuss the merits of this test strategy, but that's not the topic of the question.)

```
class PyD2LMethodsTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        with open('./soup_1899_pickle.pkl', 'rb') as soup_pickle: 
            self.soup = pickle.load(soup_pickle)
        with open('./soup_1899_details_pickle.pkl', 'rb') as details_pickle: 
            self.test_details = pickle.load(details_pickle)
        with open('./test_Match_1899_pickle.pkl', 'rb') as test_Match_pickle: 
            self.test_match = pickle.load(test_Match_pickle)
```

This results in the following series of errors in my travis build:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_calculate_reward_rounded_ceil (pyd2l_test.MatchTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/build/garth5689/pyd2l/test/pyd2l_test.py", line 70, in setUp
    with open('./test_Match_1899_pickle.pkl', 'rb') as test_Match_pickle: self.test_= pickle.load(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './test_Match_1899_pickle.pkl'
```

Here is the directory structure

```
pyd2l (repo)
|-- pyd2l
|   |-- (actual source files) 
|
+-- test
    |-- pyd2l_test.py   
    |-- soup_1899_details_pickle.pkl
    |-- soup_1899_pickle.pkl
    |-- soup_404_pickle.pkl
    +-- test_Match_1899_pickle.pkl
```

The tests all run fine on my local machine.  (I added the `./` to the file name during my testing to see if I could get it to work on my own.  I think there might be something in the environment variables that I need to work with, but I'm not sure.  There might also be the possibility that travis doesn't allow pickling/unpickling, but I couldn't find anything to that effect.  Any help is appreciated.

Travis builds: https://travis-ci.org/garth5689/pyd2l/builds

Answer (score 6):

`./` is redundant; the path to the file is already relative to your current working directory.

The problem is that you want it to instead be relative to your test directory, so:

```
import os
# ...

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'soup_1899_pickle.pkl'), 'rb') as soup_pickle:
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work: https://travis-ci.org/garth5689/pyd2l/builds/20697547.  Do you know if there's anything special in travis during the copying from the repo to their VM that could drop files out (or specifically what it copies)?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look carefully at that line of code. Do you notice something missing? Something off-balance, perhaps?

Comment: By the way, Travis is just a Linux VM. It clones your repository (`git clone`) then runs a bunch of commands. There's nothing special or magical about that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, where running the test would work well on mac system but got a FileNotFoundError when I tried to run tests on travis CI or ubuntu. Travis CI uses an ubuntu system. Say you have a folder structure:

```
project_folder:
|
+---file1.py
+---output_folder
    |
    +---output.txt
```

If your 'file1.py' has an open() function inside it that is supposed to either create the output folder and the 'output.txt' file, then running tests on ubuntu system expects you to already have the 'output_folder' on your system, or in your github repo. 'output.txt' file doesnt have to be present but the folder should. So if you have added the folder to .gitignore, then you might need to remove it. Hope that helps.