# How to handle relative python paths in travis test

Tags: python, travis-ci

I have a `unittest` that loads `json` file with `simulate(config="../data/config/default.json")` and locally it runs fine and tests are passed.

Then I pass it to `.travis.yml` with `- python -m unittest tests.test_consistency` and it cannot find this `json` file. It raises error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data/config/default.json'
```

why is that, am I missing something with relative paths?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22382861/419399) solution worked, so whatever local file I have `file.json` I changed it in the test files to:

```
CONFIG_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'file.json')
```

It makes the code harder to work with, though. I needed to overload all places where I load the files locally with

```
params.paths.G = os.path.join(root_path,  params.paths.G)  # graphml of a current .city
```